# Number guessing game will not print the right phrase

Tags: python

I am extremely new to python and this is one of the first things I have tried.  There are 3 criteria that I want this game to meet.  First is to use the number 0-10 and guess the number 3 which it does correctly.  Next is 0-25 when 11 is chosen.  This also works correctly.

However this last part has been giving me trouble.  When picking from 0-50, it should guess 1 which it does.  It should also print the "I'm out of guesses" line when another input is placed as it cannot go higher than one now.  What am I doing wrong here?

```
import random
import math

smaller = int(input("Enter the smaller number: "))
larger = int(input("Enter the larger number: "))
maxTry = math.log(larger - smaller)
count = 0
guess = int((smaller+larger)/2)

while count != maxTry:
    count += 1
    guess = int((smaller+larger)/2)
    print("Your number is ", guess)
    help = input("Enter =, <, or >: ")

    if help == ">":
        smaller = guess +1
    elif help == "<":
        larger = guess -1

    elif help == "=":
        print("Hooray, I've got it in", count, "tries")
        break

    elif count == maxTry:
        print("I'm out of guesses, and you cheated")
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `maxTry` is a log so it is not an integer, therefore it can never be equal to count.
You can either use an int for `maxTry` (cast it to int `maxTry = int(math.log(larger - smaller))`) or compute it with something different than log that will return an int.

Alternatively, your condition could be `count > maxTry` instead of equal. It would actually be a bit better conceptually.

*Note: you should not use capital letters in variable names in python but all lowercase with _ `max_try`. It is only a convention though so won't affect your program directly. You can find more info on conventions in the [PEP8 documentation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-and-variable-names)*

Comment: Technically, it requires `log base 2` guesses, rounded up to the next integer.  `math.log` gives you `log base e`, which makes the number too small.  I would suggest `maxTry = int(math.log(larger-smaller)/math.log(2) + .9)`.